# Getting asked for credentials in issues mode for sonarqube analysis

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

The analysis parameters page in the documentation states that if Anyone (the pre-existing group of users) does not have permission to perform analyses, you'll need to supply the credentials of a user with Execute Analysis permission for the analysis to run under.

I've allowed the group "Anyone" (and no other group or user) in my SonarQube instance (Version 5.4) to perform analysis in the global permissions page but I'm still getting an error message when analyzing my project with the SonarQube scanner for Maven. I have this issue since the upgrade to 5.4 from 5.3. It fails at

```
[INFO] Load user information
[DEBUG] GET 401 http://sonar.all.alcatel-lucent.com/batch/users?logins=someUser | time=78ms
```

with the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar (default-cli) on project xxxx-parent: Not authorized. Analyzing this project requires to be authenticated. Please provide the values of the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.
```

I'm running the analysis in issues mode for the needs of a Jenkins plugin. I don't get the same issue in normal mode or on other projects. While looking at the project's permission, Anyone can browse, see source code and execute analysis. I've also tried settings up a user with every right on that project and providing the credentials in parameter. I get a similar behavior but with this message:

```
Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password
```

I've also tried with a user in a group that has every right on that project. I don't really understand how to configure that execute analysis permission. I believe these 2 issues (from the 5.4 upgrade note) are involved in some way but that's just a guess.

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7174
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7242

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Alexis.

Answer (score 1):

The WS batch/users can't be accessed in anonymous way. So your first issue is expected (ie error 401 when trying to access it without credentials).

Now regarding your second attempt with credentials please provide the WS that is failing. The account you are using should have "analysis permission" either globally or for the project you want to analyse in preview mode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Julien. Even though we're now a month later, I still encounter the same issue even after updating SonarQube, maven plugin version, and bitbucket version.

The user I provide have analysis permission. I'd love to investigate more but I'm not sure what to do to help bust this one.